# Check if Callable object is function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to distinguish between a built-in function `<class 'function'>`, and any other callable object that implements `__call__` method?

Say we want a function with this definition:

```py
def is_callable_function(obj: Callable) -> bool: ...
```

and we have these callables:

```py
def function(*args, **kwargs): ...

class CallableObj1:
   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): ...

class CallableObj2:
   @classmethod
   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs): ...

class CallableObj3:
   @staticmethod
   def __call__(*args, **kwargs): ...
```

then it works like:

```py
>>> is_callable_function(function)
True
>>> is_callable_function(CallableObj1)
False
>>> is_callable_function(CallableObj2)
False
>>> is_callable_function(CallableObj3)
False
```

Technically an implementation like this one below will work:

```py
def is_callable_function(obj: Callable) -> bool:
   return type(obj).__name__ == "function"
```

but I believe that there is a better way.

Comment: Is the distinction important…?

Comment: Your last implementation is what I would use.  This does return `True` for static methods, which are basically functions attached to an object namespace.

Comment: Why not just check the `type()`?

Comment: What's the _context_, why do you want to distinguish them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inspect.isfunction(obj)` does what you want.

```
import inspect

class A:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

def a():
    ...

print(inspect.isfunction(A())) # False
print(inspect.isfunction(a)) # True
```

doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction

Answer (score 3):

You have several options in Python to detect whether some object is a function or not. The first one and most common is using `callable()` function but in your case you may be able to solve the problem by using `isinstance(yourFunction, types.FunctionType)` having imported the `types` module.

You can also check whether an object has `__call__` attribute with `hasattr(obj, '__call__')`, but I think the previous methods are better in your case.

```
import types

def function():
    return 0

class CallableObj1:
   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       pass

class CallableObj2:
   @classmethod
   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       pass

class CallableObj3:
   @staticmethod
   def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
       pass
   
#Check if object is function
print(isinstance(function, types.FunctionType))
print(isinstance(CallableObj3, types.FunctionType))

#Check if object is callable
print(callable(function))
print(callable(CallableObj3))

#Check if object has __call__ attribute, equivalent to callable()
print(hasattr(function, '__call__'))
print(hasattr(CallableObj3, '__call__'))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: Both `callable(obj)` and `hasattr(obj, "__call__")`, which are equivalent anyway, do exactly what the OP _doesn't_ want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But he can check whether a callable object is a function by combining both `callable()` and `isinstance(function, types.FunctionType)` instructions.